# IN() returns 'Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return all `place_id`s which meet ANY of the 2 criteria specified by two subqueries. Each of these subqueries can return more than 1 row, because I can have multiple places meeting a subquery's condition.

```
SELECT p.place_id
FROM places p
LEFT JOIN rel_place_custom_fields rpcf ON p.place_id = rpcf.place_id 
WHERE rpcf.place_id IN 
    ((SELECT rpcf.place_id FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf
      WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND rpcf.field_value = :value_29_0), 
     (SELECT rpcf.place_id FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf
      WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND rpcf.field_value = :value_29_1)) 
GROUP BY place_id
```

It returns the following error:

> Uncaught exception: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242
>   Subquery returns more than 1 row

What is the better way to do it? I was told that it can be done with `JOIN`, but have no idea how to do it myself.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: I don't see the need of sub queries here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
WHERE 
   rpcf.place_id IN (SELECT rpcf.place_id 
                     FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
                     WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND rpcf.field_value = :value_29_0)

   OR 

   rpcf.place_id IN (SELECT rpcf.place_id 
                     FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
                     WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND rpcf.field_value = :value_29_1)
```

or, even better:

```
WHERE 
   rpcf.place_id IN (SELECT rpcf.place_id 
                     FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
                     WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND 
                            rpcf.field_value IN (:value_29_0, :value_29_1))
```

Comment: The fist way doesn't return anything for an unknown reason, the second one works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try below script :

```
SELECT p.place_id 
FROM places p 
LEFT JOIN rel_place_custom_fields rpcf ON p.place_id = rpcf.place_id 
WHERE rpcf.place_id IN ((SELECT rpcf.place_id 
                         FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
                         WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND 
                               (rpcf.field_value = :value_29_0 OR
                                rpcf.field_value = :value_29_1)
GROUP BY place_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your inner queries returing multiple rows, so that this error coming.

You can use group_concat in select query to get all the rows with comma, So try like below,

```
SELECT 
  p.place_id 
FROM
  places p 
  LEFT JOIN rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
    ON p.place_id = rpcf.place_id 
WHERE rpcf.place_id IN (
    (SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(rpcf.place_id) 
    FROM
      rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
    WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 
      AND rpcf.field_value = :value_29_0),
    (SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(rpcf.place_id) 
    FROM
      rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
    WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 
      AND rpcf.field_value = :value_29_1)
  ) 
GROUP BY place_id
```

May this will help you

Comment: If you use group_concat() you will obtain a string in the form "1,2,3" for example. Assuming rpcf.place_id is an integer, the IN() will thus never match place_id to these strings.

Answer (score 1):

No need to JOIN, no need to GROUP BY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.place_id
FROM places p
WHERE p.place_id_id IN 
    (SELECT rpcf.place_id FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf
     WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND rpcf.field_value IN (:value_29_0, :value_29_1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.place_id
FROM places p
LEFT JOIN rel_place_custom_fields rpcf ON p.place_id = rpcf.place_id 
WHERE rpcf.place_id IN 
    ((SELECT rpcf.place_id FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf
      WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29 AND rpcf.field_value IN ('value_29_0','value_29_1')
GROUP BY place_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think so that there is a need of sub query(s) when you have joined the same table just use `WHERE` clause to filter out the results you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.place_id
FROM places p
JOIN rel_place_custom_fields rpcf ON p.place_id = rpcf.place_id 
WHERE rpcf.field_id = 29
AND rpcf.field_value IN(:value_29_0,:value_29_1)
```

Also use of group by without aggregate function is not good idea so i have used distinct instead. Another i don't see the usage of `LEFT` join your where conditions truns out that join into `INNER` join

Another approach to do the same will be something like

```
SELECT p.place_id
FROM places p
JOIN rel_place_custom_fields rpcf ON p.place_id = rpcf.place_id 
GROUP BY p.place_id
HAVING SUM(rpcf.field_id = 29)
AND SUM(rpcf.field_value IN(:value_29_0,:value_29_1))
```

Comment: Since IN() removes duplicates, your first query may produce more rows than the original. This will occur if rpcf has several identical place_id values per field_value, which is unknown...

Comment: @peufeu that is why in first query i have added `DISTINCT`, I am not sure if this is true *your first query may produce more rows than the original*

Comment: Hm, that's true, yet one version might be faster than the other depending on the number of rows that have to be removed by the distinct, and how MySQL processes the IN(), which can be surprising...